# Algorithm for evaluating chess positions with custom pieces and different board shapes

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, game-development, chess, minimax

I am in the process of designing a chess game which will feature an AI opponent to play against. The user will also have the ability to create custom chess pieces for their starting lineup by combining behaviours of current pieces they have unlocked (for example a Heroine; a hybrid of Queen and Horse) plus completely new pieces, and will also feature new board shapes different to the original 8x8.

The question then is how to design the AI. I decided I will start simple and try the minimax algorithm with alpha-beta pruning, but the problem arises in determining how to evaluate the position.

Evaluating a position with new pieces and new board shapes that can't be pre-determined at compile-time is something I have not seen people mention much, so I am stuck on how to even approach it. A simple point-wise sum of each piece value doesn't really work either because you can't score how the custom pieces. I am aware that Alpha Zero and other chess engines use a large neural network for evaluating their position.

Edit: I discussed possible architectures with a friend of mine, and we considered a theoretical architecture where the behaviour of each custome piece is encoded in a binary string, which is then combined with the board layout (which would also be a binary string) to create the first input layer of a MLP for the evaluation function, which would have a single output neuron, which outputs a number which is the evaluation of the position (positive for white and negative for black as usual).

The evaluation function is then put in a minimax to create an AI bot, and using this we make it play against itself, and to train the evaluation function we get the result of the game (1 for white wins and 0 for black) and use that to create a cost function - if white wins, then the eval function for white should have been evaluating the position as positive most of the time.

Of course, this doesn't protect against sudden mistakes the opponent may make, which completely change the tide of the game, even though they may have been winning most of the time. To rectify this, we play the same model against itself with the same game multiple times, butting adding random noise to the moves each time.

I have no clue if this would work, and I'm hoping some AI experts could point out any flaws ro alternatives.

Comment: Hi! Great problem. Do you want to figure this out by yourself, or do you want to research what has been done by other people faced with the same problem? See for instance https://www.chess.com/forum/view/chess-variants/computing-the-value-of-fairy-pieces-beyond-one-move https://www.chess.com/forum/view/chess-variants/how-can-i-figure-out-the-relative-piece-values-in-variants-i-come-up-with https://www.chess.com/forum/view/chess960-chess-variants/tips-and-tricks-using-fairy-pieces-in-various-chess-variants

Comment: More https://www.schemingmind.com/home/journalarticle.aspx?article_id=184 https://lichess.org/@/ubdip/blog/finding-the-value-of-pieces/PByOBlNB https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/39417/how-can-i-evaluate-a-position-in-4x6-chess https://www.chessvariants.com/page/MSfairy-max-an-ai-for-playing-user-defined-chess-variants

Comment: @Stef Firstly, thank you a lot for the links - the fairy stockfish were very useful. However, all of these approaches you linked still seem to be dealing with a fixed piece set - maybe I'm wrong, but this would hugely affect what algorithm I would have to use, no?

Comment: I think some of the links I gave describe approaches applicable to any fairy piece, but I didn't read in enough details to be sure. Maybe this one is better: https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/14434/how-to-determine-the-value-of-a-piece-from-scratch

Comment: But yes, if you can reuse the results from stockfish-fairy, that makes it considerably easier, but perhaps limited to the pieces that are already in stockfish.

Comment: On [this page](https://www.chessvariants.com/piececlopedia.dir/ideal-and-practical-values.html) there is this awesome paragraph: *"As it turns out, ideal values of simple one-step pieces are absurdly simple: however many different moves it can make, that's its ideal value. An Alfil moves to 4 different squares, so it is ideally worth half as much as a Knight, which moves to 8. A piece that combines the moves of Alfil and Dabaaba moves to 8 different squares, so it has the same ideal value as the Knight."*

Comment: So you could do the following: (1) Generate lots of completely random games; (2) Take all the positions from all those random games; (3) For each piece type, compute the average number of squares it can move to. How many squares a piece can move to depends on the position (since other pieces can block its path) so that's why you need to average over many games.

Comment: You could also classify the positions as either "opening" or "endgame" (just saying that the first half of a game is opening and the second half is endgame), and calculate two averages for each piece, the average number of squares it can reach in opening positions, and the average in endgame positions. This way, you can see which pieces are stronger in the opening (like bishops) and which pieces are stronger in the endgame (like rooks).

Comment: @Stef Would you say this process of generating games is quick enough to train the AI in realtime - it would need to retrain everytime the user creates a new custom piece

Comment: They're random games, so it should be pretty fast, yes. During the random game generation you don't use an AI, just randomness. If it's too complicated, instead of generating random games, then you could just generate random positions directly.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

General Game Playing (GGP) is an AI field where the rules are not known in advance of game play. So if the player unlocked new custom piece moves, you could encode those into Game Description Language (GDL) and have it play. There are many open source players available, like Cadiaplayer, Sancho, and some others.

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_game_playing
- http://cadia.ru.is/wiki/public:cadiaplayer:main
- http://sanchoggp.github.io/sancho-ggp/